# как добавить элементы массива a в массив b?

Tags: python

Есть двумерный массив a:

```
[[3, 5, 6, 4],
[5, 5, 6, 7],
[9, 5, 4, 3]]
```

И массив b:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Необходимо совместить эти два массива, чтобы получилось что-то такое:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 3, 5, 6, 4],
[0, 5, 5, 6, 7],
[0, 9, 5, 4, 3]]
```

Как реализовать это на python?
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = [[3, 5, 6, 4],
... [5, 5, 6, 7],
... [9, 5, 4, 3]]
>>>
>>> b = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
... [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
... [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
... [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>>
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
...   for j in range(len(a[i])):
...     b[len(b)-len(a) + i][len(b[i])-len(a[i]) + j] = a[i][j] # =, если нужно заменить. +=, если нужно добавить
...
>>> b
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 3, 5, 6, 4], [0, 5, 5, 6, 7], [0, 9, 5, 4, 3]]
```